# How to connect two docker containers on different VMs with VxLAN without using bridge

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

I need to connect two docker containers on different VMs but without using bridges on hosts. For now I add `vxlan` interface to bridge, but I need to get rid of bridge, because bridge can drop some packets like STP, also protocol like ebgp can't establish peer-to-peer connection because bridge standing under the hood.

I think maybe there is way to bond `veth` and `vxlan` interface